# I want to use list comprehension to make an array where it says Patient 0, Patient 1, etc

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I want to make a simple string where I put

['Patient 1', 'Patient 2', 'Patient 3'...] 61 times.

How would I do this?

I tried:

```
y_axis = ['Patient %number' for number in range(61)]
print(y_axis)
```

but it it only prints out Patient %number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
y_axis = [f'Patient {number}' for number in range(1, 62)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y_axis = ['Patient {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 62)]
print(y_axis)
```

Output:

```
['Patient 1', 'Patient 2', 'Patient 3', 'Patient 4', 'Patient 5', 'Patient 6', 'Patient 7', 'Patient 8', 'Patient 9', 'Patient 10', 'Patient 11', 'Patient 12', 'Patient 13', 'Patient 14', 'Patient 15', 'Patient 16', 'Patient 17', 'Patient 18', 'Patient 19', 'Patient 20', 'Patient 21', 'Patient 22', 'Patient 23', 'Patient 24', 'Patient 25', 'Patient 26', 'Patient 27', 'Patient 28', 'Patient 29', 'Patient 30', 'Patient 31', 'Patient 32', 'Patient 33', 'Patient 34', 'Patient 35', 'Patient 36', 'Patient 37', 'Patient 38', 'Patient 39', 'Patient 40', 'Patient 41', 'Patient 42', 'Patient 43', 'Patient 44', 'Patient 45', 'Patient 46', 'Patient 47', 'Patient 48', 'Patient 49', 'Patient 50', 'Patient 51', 'Patient 52', 'Patient 53', 'Patient 54', 'Patient 55', 'Patient 56', 'Patient 57', 'Patient 58', 'Patient 59', 'Patient 60', 'Patient 61']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
y_axis = ['Patient {}'.format(number) for number in range(1, 62)]
```